# Web Service in Java with apache axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache, apache-axis

How to invoke web service operations or methods in java from browser?

Comment: Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: I find the ending of the sentence "in java from browser" to be particularly confusing. Can you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1):

[Web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) and browsing pages in a browser are different strategies to access your web aplication. If you simply would like to run a method by sending a URL from your browser have a look at [Servlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servlet). No web service is neccessary for that. With Axis 2 you can access methods from different programms and even other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to invoke a web service without to much of a hassle is to use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

You just simply create a new project, import the wsdl it has to consume and SoapUI will create a test-envelope.